# kubernetes api-resource not found

Tags: api, kubernetes, cloud, minikube

I'm using `audit.k8s.io/v1` api to make some audit policy.

the yaml file that i use:

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1
kind: Policy
rules:
- level: Metadata
```

but when i use `kubectl api-versions` or `kubectl api-resources` to get the api-version/ api-resources I can't find the `audit.k8s.io/v1` in api list.

how can i add this api-resource in my api list ? should I do it with CRDs ? but how ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add any CRD. `audit.k8s.io/v1` is not exposed as `api-resources` or `api-versions`. It's configured directly in kubernetes API server using a flag

```
--audit-log-version string     Default: "audit.k8s.io/v1".
```

You can change it to something else via above flag if you want to.